# Is sending an e-mail using AJAX and mail() function good or bad idea?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm going to use AJAX so I can send e-mail notification in background and also not interrupting my users while using the interface.

The problem is, I don't know if it is safe, recommended, or just a worst idea.

Tried to search this on Google but no answer found. Hope someone explain to me and answer me if it is a recommended or just a bad idea.

Comment: Which data do you need to post to send the email?

Comment: A few things to note: Make sure only valid requests trigger `mail()` (else you may end up as a spamming hub). Also make sure not to send too many emails (if the user triggers the ajax to often by accident).

Comment: Not a good question, as everybody will answer with their opinion.

Comment: One thing, you should understand is, if you are doing any action on the backend or from the backend based on or due to user's interaction on the frontend, that's a loophole and will be exploited sooner or later.

Comment: It's fine if the email address is only required server-side, as in, you're sending yourself an email to your own "admin" address which never has to be displayed client-side.

Comment: Saying that, My opinion is *No*. Its a bad idea.

Comment: @Starx there is no *good* or *bad* idea. It is the same, just depends if you want to have *nice* processing or *just loading normal page*.

Comment: I have a table where the e-mail addresses are stored. My PHP code will loop through this emails row by rows, collate them, and send a notification like an *E-mail Blast* (if you can get my point).

Comment: @Mr.Spock If the email content and email address are already in a table and you are just triggering the action of sending those emails then it might be okay.

Comment: @tilz0R, As I wrote that's my opinion and if you have something to say about the reason I gave for that opinion, please do tell me, otherwise, what you are saying is not making any sense to me because its not related.

Comment: @Starx you got my point.

Comment: @TonySamperi No data being passed. I'm just pulling data from the database and send an e-mail notification. That's it.

Comment: I don't see a problem, as long as the request is properly secured (e.g. with a token)

Comment: @Mr.Spock, Ok, then you have to make sure that the action is being triggered securely, or only when intended. Javier as mentioned a way you can do it.

Comment: If you set some controls to avoid useless sends, then why not...

Comment: @TonySamperi the AJAX will only be triggered if someone created a new form.

Comment: You have my blessing, but as others suggest, you could use a token to have the max secutrity. Cheers

Comment: I recommend [PHPmailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) and [recaptcha](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/old/docs/php), just make sure you are not spamming emails cause you have a chance to be flagged as a spammer if you do (resulting in emails either not being send or enter the spam box)